# How to remove App Id attached to personal account?

Tags: ios, iphone

It's easy to remove APP ID from Apple Developer Center when you are the member of the developer program. However how can I delete app id created using regular apple account, without enrolment? Starting xcode7 users can start building using these accounts and it seems we have made an error and created an APP ID we want to use, using wrong account.